# How to get the SQL Query of a prepared statement object before execution?

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement

I am using Prepared Statement Query. But I want to know the exact sql query before it gets executed.

The Database which I am using is ORACLE

Please Suggest Any ideas .

Comment: Maybe [P6Spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy) is appropriate?

Comment: In general, it is difficult to do this, because the parameters are actually bound to the statement on your Oracle database, not in your Java code.  Why do you have this requirement?

Comment: https://developer.ibm.com/articles/j-loggable/

Comment: The exact SQL query being executed is the same that you've passed to the `PreparedStatement`. It doesn't change. The values of variables **are not part of the statement** (it has been [parsed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/sql.html#GUID-B3F2B5B8-B679-4A7C-B1E8-286F36319FCB) already), they are the data that will be passed to the database for processing. So you may log them and then do what you want.

Comment: And appropriate logging is another task, because when you use, for example `select :num_var + 1 as v from dual`, and see just `1` in the log, then you cannot say if it was string or decimal or integer or some binary stream. But they are different for the database and may or may not produce an error at the execution.

Comment: @astentx So what is the way to get the sql of the prepared statement?